# how to use Multiple functions in PIVOT or use multiple PIVOTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which in most parts works fine, however I am having issues with the second PIVOT.

Ideally it should return the count of all the instances where the column with questionId 12 is set to 1. this is a bit field.

but in all instances it returns 1 as the result.

```
SELECT 
            [1] as GeneralFeedback,
            [3] as FoodRating,
            [4] as DrinksRating,
            [5] as RestaurantAmbience,
            [6] as ServiceRating,
            [7] as BookingService,
            [12] as RecommendationsCount,
            [13] as Rating,
            [525] as ValueForMoney, 
            [526] as LocationRating,
            ReviewCount
            FROM
            (   SELECT QR.QuestionId,
                       CONVERT(DECIMAL, QR.RatingScaleOptionId) AS rating,
                       (COUNT(1) OVER ()) / 10 ReviewCount,
                       CASE WHEN QR.YesOrNoOptionAnswer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as RecommendationsCount
                FROM QuestionResponse QR
                     INNER JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON QR.SurveyResponseId = SR.SurveyResponseId
                WHERE SR.StatusId IN(5, 7)
                     AND QR.QuestionId IN(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 525, 526)
                AND SR.RestaurantNetworkId = 101368
            ) AS SourceTable 
            PIVOT(AVG(rating) FOR QuestionId IN([1],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[13],[525],[526])) AS PivotTable1
            PIVOT(COUNT(RecommendationsCount) FOR RecommendationsCount IN([12])) AS PivotTable2
```

the inner query result looks like the following picture, keep in mind that there are a total of 15 instances where RecommendationsCount is 1, 1 instance it is 0 and all other instances it is NULL.

[image]

the following is the result of the whole query:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code the pivoting yourself using conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
  SurveyID_Or_RestaurantID_Or_Something,
  AVG(CASE WHEN QuesitonID = 1  THEN Rating               END)   AS GeneralFeedback,
  AVG(CASE WHEN QuesitonID = 3  THEN Rating               END)   AS FoodRating,
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 12 THEN RecommendationsCount END)   AS RecommendationsCount
FROM
  YourTablesAndJoins
GROUP BY
  SurveyID_Or_RestaurantID_Or_Something
```

This works because there is an ***implicit*** `ELSE NULL` in all the `CASE` statements ***and*** aggregation functions ignore those `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this and it seems to be twice as slow as pivoting that's why I am trying the pivoting way.

Comment: Give your full slow query in your question.  Because I've never seen it be slower than a `PIVOT` before.  *(Also, be aware that you're saying that your get the wrong results with the faster query, you may be limited in options.)*